# Restart problem

Tags: shutdown, 16.10

I have a strange problem when selecting restart.
The computer will begin the restart process but then becomes stuck with cooling fans in hi state.
This is a feature that worked yesterday but I have since installed quite a bit of software since as it's a new build so can't be specific as to what install may have been the one that affected the shut down process.
Normal shutdown works unaffected.

Comment: How long did you wait?

Comment: Not long enough apprently! it's working fine now. Thanks for the reply.